# Processing won't run on Ubuntu 16.04 raises Exception

Tags: ubuntu, processing

I am trying to setup Processing alongside my Arduino IDE on Ubuntu 16.04. Post install, I go in and attempt running an example program and processing dumps this on me. What should I be doing?
For reference, I have JDK-8 installed.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-29" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open /home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/java/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8633,server=y,suspend=y,quiet=y -Djna.nosys=true -Djava.ext.dirs=/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/java/lib/ext -Djava.library.path=:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib -cp /tmp/Sequential810704108564722622temp:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/core.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/userDesktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/java/lib/rt.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/lib/ant.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/lib/jna-platform.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/lib/jna.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/lib/pde.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/core.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/gluegen-rt.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/core/library/jogl-all.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/JavaMode.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/antlr.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/classpath-explorer-

    1.0.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/com.ibm.icu.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/jdi.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/jdimodel.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/jdtCompilerAdapter.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/jsoup-1.7.1.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.core.contenttype.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.core.jobs.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.core.resources.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.core.runtime.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.equinox.common.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.equinox.preferences.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.jdt.core.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.osgi.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.eclipse.text.jar:/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/mode/org.netbeans.swing.outline.jar -ea processing.core.PApplet --editor-location=65,24 --external --display=1 --sketch-path=/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/modes/java/examples/Topics/Animation/Sequential Sequential
        at processing.core.PApplet.exec(PApplet.java:3510)
        at processing.mode.java.runner.Runner$1.run(Runner.java:485)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/user/Desktop/Processing/processing_3.3/java/bin/java": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
        at processing.core.PApplet.exec(PApplet.java:3508)
        ... 2 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Installed a 64-bit copy of everything and a 32-bit copy of Processing. Got the 64-bit processing, everything working okay now.

Comment: You can mark your own answer as correct if it answered your question.